# Pagination on Native sql query gives : unexpected token: ON

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, pagination

While writing a pagination query in repository as below code segment, I'm getting following error.

> Code

```
@Repository
public interface Aaaa extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TxnDealerInventoryItem, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT EM.PART_NO, EM.PART_NAME FROM TXN_DEALER_INVENTORY_ITEM E INNER JOIN MST_PRODUCT EM ON E.PRODUCT_ID = EM.PRODUCT_ID WHERE E.ACCOUNT_ID= :accountId AND EM.ALLOW_SERIAL_NUM = :isSerialized ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}",
            countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TXN_DEALER_INVENTORY_ITEM E INNER JOIN MST_PRODUCT EM ON E.PRODUCT_ID = EM.PRODUCT_ID WHERE E.ACCOUNT_ID= :accountId AND EM.ALLOW_SERIAL_NUM = :isSerialized",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Object[]> getNonSerializedDeviceList(@Param("accountId") Long accountId, @Param("isSerialized") String isSerialized, Pageable pageable);
}
```

> Error

```
HQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TXN_DEALER_INVENTORY_ITEM E INNER JOIN MST_PRODUCT EM ON E.PRODUCT_ID = EM.PRODUCT_ID WHERE E.ACCOUNT_ID= :accountId AND EM.ALLOW_SERIAL_NUM = :isSerialized
2023-02-10 18:52:52,753 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http-/127.0.0.1:8881-1) line 1:76: unexpected token: ON
```

Native Query doesn't have any error when run from sql developer.

Framework versions are as follows, Unfortunately I'cant update these any further as there are limitations in deployment environment. You inputs are highly welcome on this !!

> <spring.version>4.3.30.RELEASE</spring.version>
> <spring.data.version>1.11.23.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
> <hibernate.version>4.2.18.Final</hibernate.version>

PS : for testing purpose when I change the SQL to a very basic like a select *, It gives following error.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TXN_DEALER_INVENTORY_ITEM is not mapped [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TXN_DEALER_INVENTORY_ITEM E ]
```

Comment: These error messages do not come from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This was happened due to older spring-data-commons-1.10.RELEASE.jar that imports for Page object instead of spring-data-commons-1.13.23.RELEASE.jar with some other jars in modular project.